# Draw a rotated and scaled rectangle centered at a certain point

Tags: svg, gdi+

I'm developing a drawing program, and using GDI+ with this transform (pseudocode):

```
 TGPGraphics.TranslateTransform(100,100);
 TGPGraphics.ScaleTransform(2.2,2.2);
 TGPGraphics.RotateTransform(27); 
 TGPGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pen,-10,-5,20,10)
```

I get the result I want drawing a rectangle centered at 100,100 width = 20 and height = 10, something like this:
[image: rotated rectangle with GDI+]

Now I want to export as svg the same drawing, representing the rectangle as a symbol, and using this:

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="142.5mm" viewBox="0 0 210 142.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="140"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="180" y2="100"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<use href="#test" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(100 100) scale(2.2) rotate(27) "/>
<defs>
<symbol id="test">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" fill="#FF0000"  stroke="#008000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I get this:

[image: rectangle with svg]

Now, I need to centered the rectangle so playing with translate transform I can get something like I was searching:

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="142.5mm" viewBox="0 0 210 142.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="140"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="180" y2="100"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<use href="#test" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(85 80) scale(2.2) rotate(27) "/>
<defs>
<symbol id="test">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="10" fill="#FF0000"  stroke="#008000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
</symbol>

</defs>
</svg>
```

[image: rectangle centered changing transform]

But don't know how this transform (translate(85 80)) must be calculated. Any suggestions how to get the result correctly or how calculate the transform?.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol is not centred at the origin. The simplest thing is to transform it so that it is. Then you're rotating and scaling round the origin and everything else works out.

Unfortunately this solution doesn't work on Chrome or Safari yet as they haven't implemented this part of the SVG 2 specification, but it does work on Firefox.

```html
<svg width="210mm" height="142.5mm" viewBox="0 0 210 142.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="140"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="180" y2="100"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<use href="#test" transform="translate(100 100) scale(2.2) rotate(27) "/>
<defs>
<symbol id="test" transform="translate(-10, -5)">
<rect width="20" height="10" fill="#FF0000"  stroke="#008000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: But , what I want is to center the rectangle at 100,100 . not the origin of rectangle

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't explained well. the center of the rectangle must be at 100,100 , as the first gdi+ drawing do.

Comment: Center of rectangle, not the top left corner. I want as the first image. Anyway changing th <symbol> tag with <g> I get the result I want, as I explain in answering my question.

Comment: Ahh, you're using Chrome aren't you and that browser seems to be buggy. My solution does work on Firefox.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Chrome and Edge doesn't centered the rectangle with your code, but Firefox show correctly. Thanks for you suggestions. As I explained with my answer, changing <symbol> with <g> draw it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

changing the 'symbol' tag per 'g' tag, I get the correct drawing. Trying to get the same result as the gdi+ drawing I use this svg:

```
<svg width="210mm" height="142.5mm" viewBox="0 0 210 142.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="140"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="180" y2="100"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<use href="#test" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(100 100) rotate(27) scale(2.2)"/>
<defs>
<symbol id="test">
<rect x="-10" y="-5" width="20" height="10" fill="#FF0000"  stroke="#008000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
</symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
```

But this crops the rectangle and show only a 1/4 part:

[image: croped rectabgle with symbol tag]

Now, changing the symbol tag with g tag:

```
<svg width="210mm" height="142.5mm" viewBox="0 0 210 142.50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="140"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<line x1="0" y1="100" x2="180" y2="100"  stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
<use href="#test" x="0" y="0" transform="translate(100 100) rotate(27) scale(2.2)"/>
<defs>
<g id="test">
<rect x="-10" y="-5" width="20" height="10" fill="#FF0000"  stroke="#008000" stroke-width="0.1"/>
</g>
</defs>
</svg>
```

I get the correct drawing:

[image: correct drawing]